# How to put authentication on a EPIServer page

Tags: episerver, episerver-7, episerver-6

I have created a page type from EPIServer admin and based on that created a page in EPIServer. Now I want to put authentication on that page so that only login user and user with a certain user id can access that page from front end.No guest user will be able to access that page.How to implement that in EPIServer,In setting section of a page type there is a option access role but it is not working. Still anonymous user are able to access that page. What is the option to put restriction on that page .Please share link of tutorial.

My navigating url is

```
http://wwww.xyz.com/en/Documents/
```

and in web.config I have written like this

```
 <location path="Documents">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"></deny>
      </authorization>

    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Answer (score 2):

Access rights for a page is set from Edit or Admin Mode. No config file change or code is needed, it's completely built-in to EPiServer.

Answer (score 1):

Sign in to EPiServer's edit-mode. Navigate to your newly created page in the *navigation pane*. If you click the "**All properties**" (or scroll up), "**Visible to: Everyone**" will be presented. Choose "**Manage**" from where you can select which users and groups that will have access to this item as well as what the are allowed to do with it.